# How to get string and string length in linux kernel mode?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm actually new to the linux kernel mode programming.
I have to get a input from a user mode program test.c,
and write it into my driver kernel mydrv.c

What i did is get a string input by scanf, and   and wrote it as
write(file, out, MAX_SIZE);

file is a device and out is input string.
in mydrv_write, i tried to get a string length of input by strlen,
But process terminated whenever i try to implement it 
I included  in front of the program.

I guess the input string out isn't properly got into the kernel.
So how to get a string length inside the kernel?

Comment: It is 3d argument to `write` which contains the length of the written buffer. Instead `MAX_SIZE` you need to pass actual length of the string you write.

Comment: You have to read as many bytes s user provides, and `write()` actually can be split to several calls in a row. This, you need to have a buffer and understanding what would be the end marker if the user input. Usually for thing like you described the sysfs node is used.

Answer (score 1):

did you try something like this :

```
#define strLength(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
```

but this marco give you size of whole string array. and now i look at some linux source code. `linux-4.19.3/drivers/bluetooth/btmrvl_sdio.c:1471` :

```
fw_dump_ptr += strlen("========Start dump ");
```

i think there is no problem to use `strlen` or any `string.h` functions in your program.